# Replace is adding to end of string

Tags: c#, replace

I am trying to do a simple replace. My problem is that instead of replacing the string, it appears it grabs the last couple characters and appends them to the end.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string> {
{"1", @"\\id 1ch\n fjdsbfjdshfd"},
{"2", @"\\id 1co\n fjdsbfjdshfd"},
{"3", @"\\id 1th\n fjdsbfjdshfd"}
};

public static string bookNameFn(string line)
{
    return line.Split(' ')[1].ToLower().Replace("1ch", "1Chr").Replace("1co", "1Cor").Replace("1th", "1Thess");
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> usfm in dict)
{
    foreach (var line in usfm.Value.Split('\n'))
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("\\id "))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bookNameFn(line));
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
1Chrr
1Corr
1Thessess
```

desired output

```
1Chr
1Cor
1Thess
```

Comment: The output posted seems correct for the code given

Comment: Sorry, I was commenting when you edited the question and I reloaded so I read the title "output" and the the desired output at the bottom

Comment: The posted code doesn't compile. I get a "Unrecognized escape sequence" for the '\i'.

Comment: What happens when you print each value of split in bookNameFn?

Comment: Your code snippet fails to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use literal notation e.g.

```
@"\id 1th\n fjdsbfjdshfd";
```

It will work, the problem is the way the value is interpreted through the string constructor.

Comment: It looks like he actually wants `"\\id 1ch\n fjdsbfjdshfd"`.

Comment: How can I define a string literal from a variable with the "Add" method for the dictionary? `dict.Add("1", "@"+string)`

Comment: How can you not accept my first answer and then post a new question for me to answer ? ;)